# Defining a circle/sphere geofence using PyMongo/ GeoJSON

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo

I'm working on a problem where in one part, I have to define 'hotspots' which are circles/spheres around a central point, and in the other, I have to identify if a specific (user-defined) point lies within any of these hotspots.

Problem 1: According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691956/how-to-define-a-circle-using-geojson), [the standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946) does not contain the definition of a circle using GeoJSON. The accepted answer to the question references a library, but written in JS. Do we have the equivalent or an alternative way to define a sphere/circle in Python? (3.x would be nice, but i'm willing to port if not.)

Problem 2:  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866490/mongodb-check-if-a-point-is-inside-a-stored-polygon) answers a scenario where I can find if my user's location is within any defined polygons. The question is, can I use $centerSphere in any way to define the polygon in question? If not, then what are my alternatives?

Comment: See this answer for how to compute a check for location presence in a geofence. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33589170/5189811

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @OluwafemiSule. I'll check it out! However implementing this answer will mean downloading the data of each and every hotspot and manual checking - not very efficient, i'm afraid.